# How to make box bigger in CSS3, with the position of text fixed?

Tags: html, css

How can I make box (border-radius) size bigger in CSS3? If I set `height` property, such as `height:10%`, it doesn't change, but `width:10%` makes the width of box wider. I don't know why such inconsistency occurs. Also, when I resize the height by `height: 100px`, the box size changes, but the text size remains the same, despite writing `vertical-align: middle`. So how can I correctly make the box size larger but the text position is located in the middle of the box?

Also, why does the position of box move when the mouse hovers over the box and not?

I wrote JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rXNmA/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read this [Easily center text vertically, with SVG](http://lea.verou.me/2013/03/easily-center-text-vertically-with-svg/) if you want to use svg.

the position of the box changes because of  `padding: 0px;`

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;/* remove this*/
    margin: 0px;
}
```

and bootstrap is added on you left side not in the css

and the correct link for that looks like this

under **External Resources**
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap-theme.css

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/rXNmA/2/

and for the position of the text you can use the

```
class=text-center
```

and

```
line-height: 2em;
```

or

```
line-height: 2%;
```

depending on what you want to achive

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/rXNmA/5/

Comment: Thanks for the good clarification. One more question... when I hover over dropdown menu, the dropped menu (`B` and `C` in this case) doesn't look good, since it is put on the embedded box and I don't want to show that redundant background space (in other words I want to show `B` and `C` as wide as the background box). It's pretty hard to explain it in my English (I'm not English-native), so sorry if I fails to make myself understood, but is it feasible to change it to fit my needs here?

Comment: Also, I just found that `line-height` doesn't position the text in the middle of the box. It just changes the position of the text arbitrary. And what's the `class=text-center`? It Looks like it's not the officially-defined class.

Comment: you can user overflow:hidden; on .dropdown-menu li:hover

Comment: No, it's not what I want to do... If you hover over `A`, then the dropped-menu (consisted of `B` and `C`) appears, right? However, behind `B` and `C`, there is one big, redundant block and within the block, both `B` and `C` are located, right? I want to remove that block (or make both `B` and `C` to the same width as the block behind)...

Answer (score 1):

you can not hide that div you can only make it transparent

```
div{
background:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't take the percentage height, because this div size depends of the "whole page" tall. Change the body to 100% height and it will work.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 10%;
}
```

[Vertical text alignment](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)